# Window function for grouping

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am attempting to group items in a python dataframe by a specific column. I need to get the Minimum number of customers per ID while maintaining the different names. This would be similar to SQLs window function MIN() OVER (PARTITION BY).

Here is what I have:

```
ID       Name          Customers
1        Jon Smith     5
1        James Smith   3
2        David         7
3        Saul          5
3        Samuel        10
3        Paul          2
```

Result

```
ID       Name          Customers
1        Jon Smith     3
1        James Smith   3
2        David         7
3        Saul          2
3        Samuel        2
3        Paul          2
```

Does anyone know a function for dataframe that will do this?

Comment: Please elaborate the logic. I don't get how you got that result from your input?

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar - I updated the question. I am looking for the minimum number of customers over the ID column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### `transform`

You want to broadcast a reduction over the original index.  Use `transform`.  This is the intended way to perform this action and is fast.

```
df.assign(Customers=df.groupby('ID').Customers.transform('min'))

   ID         Name  Customers
0   1    Jon Smith          3
1   1  James Smith          3
2   2        David          7
3   3         Saul          2
4   3       Samuel          2
5   3         Paul          2
```

Using `assign` is my preference as it will not overwrite the original `df` and you can place this in a new variable or overwrite the one you have.

The equivalent way to do this without assign while overwriting your dataframe:

```
df['Customers'] = df.groupby('ID').Customers.transform('min')
```

---

#### Numpy

This is more than you need but I like to show a way to do even faster with Numpy

```
i, u = pd.factorize(df.ID)
c = df.Customers.to_numpy()
o = np.empty(len(u), dtype=c.dtype)
o.fill(c.max())
np.minimum.at(o, i, c)
df.assign(Customers=o[i])

   ID         Name  Customers
0   1    Jon Smith          3
1   1  James Smith          3
2   2        David          7
3   3         Saul          2
4   3       Samuel          2
5   3         Paul          2
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `groupby()` with `map()`

```
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,1,2,3,3,3], 'Name':['Jon Smith','James Smith','David','Saul','Samuel','Paul'],'Customers':[5,3,7,5,10,2]})

x = df.groupby('id')['Customers'].min()
df['Customers'] = df['id'].map(x)
```

Output:

```
    id  Name       Customers
0   1   Jon Smith   3
1   1   James Smith 3
2   2   David       7
3   3   Saul        2
4   3   Samuel      2
5   3   Paul        2
```

Comment: Turning into a `dict` is not necessary.  `map` will work just as well with a `pandas.Series`: `df.ID.map(df.groupby('ID')['Customers'].min())`